# How to get the top 7 items in listbox

Tags: listbox, windows-phone

how can I remove the top 7 items in a listbox?

```
    int end = Count + 7;
                    for (int i = Count; i < end; i++)
                    {
                        page.nuus.Items.Add(page.local_story_list[i]);
                    }
```

this happens when the bottom of a scroller is reached, then the latest 7 items gets added to the list, however I want to remove the previous 7 items before this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first item 7 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (page.nuus.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        page.nuus.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```